# Friedman's test for binary data - possible or not?

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, binary-data

If my dependent variable is a technique scored as 1 for correct step and zero for incorrect can I use Friedmans test to compare technique scores at 3 time points?

Answer (score 5):

When the repeated-measures or related-samples data are dichotomous Friedman nonparametric test degenerates into [Cochran's Q test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test) (Friedman's chi-square statistic becomes identical to Cochran's Q statistic) which is the extension of [McNemar's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) from 2 to several related samples. McNemar's uses exact binomial computation of p-value, while Cochran relies on normal approximation, although exact p is available too, via permutations approach.